# Starting Rails thin from remote machine in background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, ssh, thin

I had created an rails app which is using thin server for starting it .

i had deployed that machine on a ubuntu virtual machine .

i loggedin in to that machine via ssh and start the server via

thin start -R config.ru &

so that i have it should run in background .

so far so good i am able to access my rails app properly from remote machine.

as i logged out from my ssh terminal from the remote machine .

my application stop responding.

is there any other way around to start application in background from remote machine .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run it with:

```
rails server thin -d
```

And it should stay in background even when you log out.

Comment: That's really impressive!